# How to use a VLOOKUP to get a column value based on another column value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have two Excel sheets, the first one looks like this:

[image]

And this is the second one:

[image]

Basically, I would like to fill in the column **Value** in the second sheet with the text from the **Answer Column** in the first sheet, but only when the value of the **Question** column is 3.

If there was no condition involved, I would simply use a VLOOKUP and be done, but is it possible to do a conditional VLOOKUP like this?

Answer (score 0):

In **J2 Cell** of **Sheet2**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!D2:D10,MATCH(TRUE,--(Sheet1!B2:B10=Sheet2!H2)*Sheet1!C2:C10=SUMPRODUCT(MAX((Sheet1!B2:B10=Sheet2!H2)*Sheet1!C2:C10)),0)),"")
```

Array formula requires CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER instead of normal enter.

Comment: Misread your post.  Updated the initial post with revised formula.

Comment: Ok, it looks like we are getting closer, but for some reason, this always returns the last line for that user (I noticed that by renaming "Something" to "Something1", "Something2" etc).

Comment: What is your actual condition?

Comment: I'll try to clarify. I need to display a column value (in this case, column **Answer**) only if the question number is 3. It is *always* going to be question number 3. So, for each user ID, which can have multiple answers and questions, the column I am trying to fill should always contain the answer to question number 3, no matter how many answers that user gave.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate your `UserId` column with Number '3' and do the same treatment in your first worksheet as well. Then do a `Vlookup` with concatenated value.

Something like this:

```
=Vlookup(1234&3,"Your array concatenated with 3",2,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the business:

```
=INDEX($D$3:$D$9,MATCH(H3&3,$B$3:$B$9&$C$3:$C$9,0))
```

Note: this is an array formula and it is applied with **Ctrl** + **Shift** + **Enter**